# Identifying Point(nan nan) in GeoPandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a GeoPandas dataframe with a Point geometry. The dataframe was created from a Pandas dataframe that contained separate columns for easting and northings using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'easting':[545200.0,np.nan,360800.0,270500.0,np.nan],
                   'northing':[130600.0,np.nan,510100.0,80350.0,np.nan]})

geodf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.drop(['easting','northing'],axis = 1),
                         crs = {'init': 'eps:277000'},
                         geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['easting'],
                                                             df['northing'])])

phjCPHEastNrthGDF = gpd.GeoDataFrame(phjCPHEastNrthDF.drop(['easting','northing'],
                                                           axis = 1),
                                     crs = {'init': 'epsg:27700'},
                                     geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(phjCPHEastNrthDF['easting'],
                                                                         phjCPHEastNrthDF['northing'])])
```

The Pandas dataframe and the GeoPandas dataframe are printed as follows:

Original dataframe:

```
   id   easting  northing
0   1  545200.0  130600.0
1   2       NaN       NaN
2   3  360800.0  510100.0
3   4  270500.0   80350.0
4   5       NaN       NaN
```

Geopandas dataframe:

```
   id               geometry
0   1  POINT (545200 130600)
1   2        POINT (nan nan)
2   3  POINT (360800 510100)
3   4   POINT (270500 80350)
4   5        POINT (nan nan)
```

In reality, the dataframe contains 250k+ points. I would like to be able to identify all the points which were created from easting and northing values of np.nan (but the original 'easting' and 'northing' columns are no longer available).

I've tried using `.isna()` and `.is_empty` but with no success:

```
print(geodf.loc[(geodf['geometry'].isna()),:])
print(geodf.loc[(geodf['geometry'].is_empty),:])
```

...both print empty dataframes.

Is there any way to identify the required geometry points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
geodf[geodf['geometry'].is_valid]
```

Result:

```
   id                       geometry
0   1  POINT (545200.000 130600.000)
2   3  POINT (360800.000 510100.000)
3   4   POINT (270500.000 80350.000)
```

to get the `Nan`-points use `geodf[~geodf['geometry'].is_valid]`

---

**Update**:
The above is valid for shapely versions up to 1.7.2. Starting from version 1.8 a point created from `np.nan` values is considered empty and hence `is_empty` works as expected:

```
   id                       geometry
0   1  POINT (545200.000 130600.000)
1   2                    POINT EMPTY
2   3  POINT (360800.000 510100.000)
3   4   POINT (270500.000 80350.000)
4   5                    POINT EMPTY
```

Result of `geodf[~geodf['geometry'].is_empty]`:

```
   id                       geometry
0   1  POINT (545200.000 130600.000)
2   3  POINT (360800.000 510100.000)
3   4   POINT (270500.000 80350.000)
```

Comment: This is strange, because for a shapely point, `.is_empty` tells me whether it cointains np.nan (Shapely==1.8.2)

Comment: @MarkusKaukonen this was changed in 1.8; for version 1.7.1 `Point(np.nan, np.nan).is_empty` returned `False`. See also last paragraph [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html#consistent-creation-of-empty-geometries). Thanks for the comment, I've updated the answer.